# jest mock a module with another module

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

EDIT : issue is fixed, see below

I'm using Jest on my app and I'd like to mock a module with another one. In other word, I would like the first module to be replaced by the second one when called in the tests.

It works fine if I put the mocking code inside the test file, like this :

```
*src/app/module.js*
export default {
  method : () => //doSomethingComplicated
}

*src/__tests__/test.js*
import module from "../app/module.js"
jest.mock("..app/module.js", () => {
  return {
    method : () => //doSomethingSimpler
  }
)
```

However I didn't success in refactoring my code in a separated file, something like this :

```
*src/app/module.js*
export default {
  method : () => //doSomethingComplicated
}

*src/__mocks__/mockModule.js*
export default {
  method : () => //doSomethingSimpler
}

*src/__tests__/test.js*
import mockModule from "../__mocks__/mockModule.js"
import module from "../app/module.js"
jest.mock("..app/module.js", () => {
  return mockModule
})
```

I get an error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

I tried to name the export but I've got the same kind of error : "Cannot read property 'mockModule' of undefined" (MockModule was the name of the export)

I also try the ES6 fix from the Jest documentation. the tests run in this case but they fail with the error : TypeError: Cannot set property 'method' of undefined

```
jest.mock('../app/module.js', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(() => mockModule)
  };
});
```

So it seems that I'm doing something wrong in the factory of the jest mocking, but I cannot figure out what's  the issue... Do you have any suggestion ?
Thanks a lot

**Edit** : I fixed the issue by myself, looking more deeply in the docs : https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

briefly : the mocking module should be placed in a sub-directory `/__mocks__/` in the same directory than the module to mock. Then you just need to call `jest.mock("../app/myModule")`, without any factory parameter: Jest will find automatically the mock and replace the original module with this one.

Comment: Edit the post to give the fix I've found